# Unit Testing method which uses class which is not in classpath

Tags: java, unit-testing, properties, mocking, junit4

I have a method which is used to check if the given class is instance of perticular type. 
 Say for example myClass is an instance of DBClass I want to return true.
 And the DBClass is dynamically defined by customer in the properties file.
 So I am reading the properties file, getting the DBClass super type , loading it and checking if given class (i.e myClass) is instance of the DBClass.

And one thing is for sure that the DBCLass which i am trying to check for supertype will not be present in my classpath at running the test case as this dbClass is dynamic and customer specific.

I am not sure how to directly test it or cover it.I am not sure if I need to mock properties file?

I am using Junit and JMock.

Any suggestions on testing the method.
Method is written something like this.

```
public boolean isDBClass (final Class<?> myClass) {
 //Following line reads the properties file and get the class name for db parent class.
String dbSuperClass = PropertiesReader.PropertyEnum.DB_CLASS_PARENT.toString();
// if myClass is subclass of dbSuperClass return true, false otherwise.
return loadClass(dbSuperClass).isAssignableFrom(myClass);
```

}

Comment: I don't think you can test something that is not in your classpath, how should the clr know what the class looks like.

Comment: @Damokles, For class not in class path may be I can add a dummy class in the classpath. But in the properties file the DB_CLASS_PARENT property will refer to the real class. Anyway to make it refer to the dummyClass?

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have find out a work around currently.
I am providing the a dummy properties file which refers to the dummy class which is in my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Your method's responsibilities are:

- get a String
- pass it to method called loadClass()
- call isAssignableFrom() with the supplied input parameter
- return the result

If you could mock the loadClass method then you could verify these responsibilities without actually doing any class loading.

You may need to do a little refactoring in order to make loadClass mock-able but that approach would unit this particular method.

Comment: thanks. Will mocking this method give me coverage? Currently I have stubbed out this method by overriding and returning false. But I am not getting coverage.